# The superconductor's electromagnetic response and Meissner current

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, superconductivity, transport-phenomena, quantum-transport

We know

> "In the superconducting state, the DC electrical resistivity is zero."

But other situations has confused me a bit. There are several situations that superconductors interact with electromagnetic fields:

**(1)Direct current electric field**

**(2)Alternative electric field**

**(3)Static magnetic field**

**(4)light**

Under these situations, how to calculate the conductivity of superconductors? And which kinds of currents(current or Meissner current) contribute to conductivity? Which parts of superconductors(superfluid ground state part or quasi-particle excitation part) can contribute to conductivity?

Answer (score 0):

"Conductivity" in reference to an actual superconductor doesn't really make sense.

Conductivity is in relation to materials that obey forms of ohms law, and is a proportionality constant between an applied electric field and current density.

The commonly prescribed Conductivity for superconductors is $\infty$, but that still doesn't make sense since that would mean the current is infinity for any electric field. Current in a superconductor should be modelled as free electrons, or:

$$\frac{d\vec{J}}{dt}=\frac{e^2n}{m} \vec{E}$$

Comment: But the superconductors have photoconduction. Like this paper: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.47.9017